# Roots of a cosine polynomial

Tags: polynomials

For $x \in [0,\pi/2]$ and $n \geq 1$ consider the cosine polynomial $P(x)=a_0\cos(x)+a_1\cos(3x)+\ldots+a_n\cos((2n+1)x)$, where the $a_i$'s are positive numbers such that $a_0>a_1>\ldots>a_n$ .
Can anything be said about the location of the roots of P ?

Answer (score 1):

Assume without loss of generality that $a_0=1$. The roots of $P$ must all lie to the right of the smallest positive root of
$$
\cos x+\cos(3\,x)+\dots+\cos(2\,n+1)x=\frac{\sin(2\,(n+1)\,x)}{2\sin x},
$$
which is $\dfrac{\pi}{2(n+1)}$.

Comment: Can you give more details ? Thanks

Comment: You say "The roots of P must all lie to the right of the smallest positive root of ...". Why is it so ?